# Trigger on Task Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to write a trigger to update the 'Name' field (so WhoId in the API) to the 'Name' (ContactId) of the custom Primary Contact field of the Account the Task is related to.

```
trigger updateNameToPrimary on Task (after insert, after update) {
    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        t.WhoID = [SELECT Account.Id 
                   FROM Account 
                   WHERE Id = :t.Id].Custom_Primary_Contact__c;        
    }
}
```

I have been doing some testing and don't think it's working and cannot figure out why. Just looking for a point in the right direction as I still am in the learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Change Trigger from "after insert after update" To "before insert before update".
Something like this

```
trigger updateNameToPrimary on Task (before insert, before update) {
    set<Id> accIdSet = new  set<Id>();
    for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
       if(t.AccountId!=null)
        accIdSet.add(t.AccountId);        
    }
   map<Id,Account> accMap = new map<Id,Account>([select Custom_Primary_Contact__c from Account where Id in:accIdSet]); 
   for(Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if(t.AccountId!=null && accMap.containsKey(t.AccountId))
        t.WhoID = accMap.get(t.AccountId).Custom_Primary_Contact__c;      
    }
}
```